# What is causing stripes in my jpg files?

Tags: jpg

Wherever I download or upload a .jpg picture from my PC, even directly from my phone to my PC or mail it, I get this displayed instead of the .jpg picture.

Can't find a single similar problem on the internet, and I am completely clueless what is causing this.
[image]

Comment: Bad RAM.........

Comment: Stop using your computer, and take to a technician. Priority 1 is to backup your files.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced user, built my system by my self and years ago. If the problem was a bad ram module, I would experience problems across the system, since pics doesn't own a reserved RAM space. Will however run the Ram Test just to be sure.